Dehydration of isoborneol with carbocation rearrangement
What rearrangement happens when isoborneol (structure below) is heated with acid?

Since acid is used and the hydroxyl group is present, the reaction mechanism is dehydration.
My attempt:

In the first step, the oxonium ion forms, which is then removed, creating the carbocation.
After this, a ring expansion takes place for one of the 5 membered rings inside the cycle, creating a stable 6 membered ring.
However after this I'm a bit confused on how to proceed.
Since there is a dimethyl group between the two bridgeheads of the bicycle, a double bond cannot form. Additionally, the bridge head carbons cannot form the double bond due to Bredt's Rule (which is valid here, as the total number of carbon atoms in the  largest ring is less than 8).
This implies we might have to migrate the carbocation to one of the carbon atoms on the outermost ring via 1,2 - $\ce{H-}$ shifts. However, I'm very unsure of that approach.
I feel as though I'm off by a large margin as the final answer differs from the mechanism so far.
Final answer:




What is going wrong with my mechanism, and why is it so much different from the final answer? Any input would be appreciated.

All you need is one positive charge. Lose a proton from the methyl group in the final structure to form camphene. Learn to draw [2.2.1]-bicycloheptanes in 3-D.

I changed this initial structure. Redrawing your scheme wouldn't be bad idea.

@user55119 How do you go from my final structure to camphene? What happened to the 3 methyl groups in the inner bridge? If you could post this as an answer, along with the mechanism, I'll gladly give you my upvote.

"why is it so much different from the final answer?" It's not. Just deprotonate and that's the product. Your main issue here dearth of 3-D imagination.

Lose a proton on the methyl next to the cation to get an exocyclic double bond.

@user55119 I understand now. But then why did the inner bridge with the 3 methyl groups become an outer bridge? Is it some form of isomerism? Or did I draw the compound wrong in the first place?

Bongo Man: Although a 2-D mechanism may get you to the final product, it is difficult to appreciate the subtleties of the rearrangement. One must use a 3-D representation to see where various atoms wind up. Isoborneol (1), a.k.a. exo-borneol,1,2 undergoes protonation of the hydroxyl group with a lose of water to form the more stable tertiary carbocation 3a. The red bonds in isoborneol illustrate favorable overlap of orbitals.3 In canonical terms one could have invoked the initial formation of the less stable secondary carbocation. Clearly, the secondary to tertiary carbocation is the driving force. The transition state is most likely the bridged carbocation 2 where the partial $\ce{C1-C6}$ bond is longer than the $\ce{C2-C6}$ bond. Rotation of carbocation 3a ~90o CCW about an axis perpendicular to the page produces view 3b. Lose of a proton from $\ce{C10}$ affords camphene 4.


The term exo arises from a hypothetical Diels-Alder reaction between diene 5 (red box) and an alkene of the $\ce{C2 and C3}$ bond  forming the minor D-A product. The endo alcohol is borneol.

Without searching the literature, I would surmise that the rate of the reaction of isoborneol is faster than for the endo isomer, borneol, which does not have favorable overlap. If this be the case, then there would be no participation of the $\ce{C1 and C6}$ bond until the secondary carbocation is formed.


ChemDraw 22.0.0.22 gives the configuration of isoborneol as 1S,2R.4R rather than 1R,2R,4R.



Thank you for your answer.  However, why did bridge in 3a rotate 90 degrees, forming 3b? It aligns with the final answer, but is there some stability criteria being met?

3a and 3b Are identical!!! Make a molecular model and rotate it from one structure to the other.

You are right! They have the same IUPAC name too. Thank you for helping me out.
